# Misunderstanding how the redirection from old domain to new domain work

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, url-rewriting

I have two domains

- olddomain.com
- newdomain.com

The `olddomain.com` doesn't have hosting account to it and I've redirected it with the DNS's only and when someone tried to open `olddomain.com` is redirected to the `newdomain.com`.

This works great for the domain name.

The problem is that the pages and the URL's doesn't match between the old and new domain(site) because the new site has a new URL structure.

So, if for example, I try to open one of the old URL's `olddomain.com/page-1/` I've got redirected to `newdomain.com/page-1` which doesn't exists and land on the 404 error page. This will be a problem for google I guess because of the missing page.

Is there any way that I can redirect all sub-pages to the home page of the new domain?

I have tried this in the `.htaccess` **on the new domain** but doesn't seems to work:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} olddomain\.com$ 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://newdomain.com/$1 [R=301,L]


RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

The main goal is to not get a penalty from Google.

Comment: I bet you cannot test your `olddomain` for `%{HTTP_HOST}` in your `newdomain` because you have already been redirected.. So i guess you need to check old structure against new one, but you didn't give any detail about that

Comment: Is there any solution for this without having a hosting account dedicated to the `olddomain`?

Comment: The old site is ... really old and no one tough about the urls. So, most of the url's like `pc_url_2479778`, `pc_url_24797`, `pc_url_32421` and so on .. and they are indexed by google like this...

Comment: There might be another server variable that keeps track of the original url before redirection, I'll take a look when I have time

Comment: Explain what _exactly_ “and I've redirected it with the DNS's only and when someone tried to open olddomain.com is redirected to the newdomain.com” means.

Comment: _“The main goal is to not get a penalty from Google.”_ - if the old content does not exist any more, then you should let it run into the 404. (Or rather a 410 GONE.) If the old URLs have equivalents in the new system, you should redirect them there. But redirecting all stuff that doesn’t exist any more to the home page, makes little sense to begin with.

Comment: Hey @04FS, thanks for the comments. I've added in the dns of the `olddomain.com` the nameservers of the `newdomain.com`. No, the new domain and new site don't have pages that are equivalent. You mean that is better to let google to go on 404 page than to home page? Why is that?

Comment: Because otherwise you would be telling Google that all the content from those pages that don’t exist any more can now be found on your index page - which does not make much sense, if that is not actually the case.

Comment: No, is not the case. I wanted to redirect them to home because they don't exist anymore and tough that this is the right way.

Comment: If there is no equivalent for the pages of `olddomain.com` in the new one, redirecting to the index can make sense for the users that used to visit the old site, but as 04FS said, not for Google. I would probably ask in Google tools to de-reference the old URLs at some point when pages of the new domain start to be referenced

Comment: @Kaddath, sorry but how do you ask Google to `de-reference` URLs?

Comment: You have to be able to access webmaster tools, [see this link](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/1663419?hl=en)

Comment: @Kaddath, Yes, I own it and have the access. Thank you all for the information.